# How to apply custom scheduler for kubernetes(kubeadm)

Tags: kubernetes

When I test Custom scheduler, but my pods status is still pending.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/

I made a new custom scheduler and 3 test pods like k8s sample yaml
but, pods using 'default-scheduler' works well, but pods using 'my-scheduler' doesn't work.

I don't know how to fix this problem.
Please help me.

1.Environment:

1. Kubernetes version (use `kubectl version`):

   Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.5", GitCommit:"cce11c6a185279d037023e02ac5249e14daa22bf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-07T16:16:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
   Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.5", GitCommit:"cce11c6a185279d037023e02ac5249e14daa22bf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-07T16:05:18Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
2. Cloud provider or hardware configuration:
3. OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release):

   NAME="CentOS Linux"
   VERSION="7 (Core)"
   ID="centos"
   ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
   VERSION_ID="7"
   PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
   ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
4. Kernel (e.g. `uname -a`):

   Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 22 21:09:27 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

2.procedure

1. kubectl apply -f my-schudler.yaml

[image]

2. when i setup ks8s using kubeadm, authorization option set to Node, RBAC, so I modified clusterrole like this
   kubectl edit clusterrole system:kube-scheduler

[image]

3. kubectl apply -f no.yaml
4. kubectl apply -f default.yaml
5. kubectl apply -f my-scheduler.yaml
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please share the the content of your my-scheduler.yaml. Did you submit all the pod configs to a Kubernetes cluster before submitting the scheduler deployment config? From your commands, I can see no.yaml executing first, this is possibly what’s causing the issue. Order is important with scheduling.

Can you also check the event and Linux system logs for container issues with the keyword “Scheduled”, you might see the problems and you can share the log file. [This wiki](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki) can give you more information on Kubernetes operations, too.